# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_20" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 784), found shape=(50, 28, 28)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, error-handling

it's my first time writing a program in python and i am following a paper that my professor gave me but i keep getting an error when runing the model.fit()

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import keras 
from keras.datasets import mnist
import seaborn as sns
```

```
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()

m = X_train.shape[0]

X_train = X_train/255
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],-1).T
X_test = X_test/255
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],-1).T 

X_train.shape,X_test.shape
```

```
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()
for i in range(9):
  plt.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
  plt.imshow(X_train[i], cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
plt.show()
```

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from keras.optimizers import Adam
```

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(units=10, input_shape=(784,), activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.01), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()



batch_size=50
epoch=5
model.fit(X_train,Y_train,batch_size,epoch)
```

[the model summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHUZq.png)[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjg4D.png)

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that your input size is `(28, 28)`, while you've set the input shape as `input_shape=(784,)`. To solve this, you should add a `Flatten()` layer to reshape the input data. Here's the modified code:

```
model = Sequential([
    Flatten(),
    Dense(units=10, input_shape=(784,), activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=10, activation='softmax')
])
```

Another point is about the loss function. Since the labels in the MNIST dataset have only one element, you should replace `categorical_crossentropy` with `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.

BTW, your current model architecture might not perform well in terms of accuracy. Here is an example of the training results:

```
Epoch 1/5
1200/1200 [==============================] - 4s 3ms/step - loss: 2.5401 - accuracy: 0.1108
Epoch 2/5
1200/1200 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 2.3023 - accuracy: 0.1088
Epoch 3/5
1200/1200 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 2.3024 - accuracy: 0.1098
Epoch 4/5
1200/1200 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 2.3023 - accuracy: 0.1110
Epoch 5/5
1200/1200 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 2.3022 - accuracy: 0.1087
```

However, this is not a programming issue. I recommend adding `Conv2D` and `MaxPooling2D` layers to your model for improved performance. check this: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-convolutional-neural-network-from-scratch-for-mnist-handwritten-digit-classification/